# ImportError: No module named my_package.msg

Tags: rospy, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I have created a package, that contains custom messages. They seem to be compiled correctly. Because I can call

```
rosmsg package my_package
```

and get

```
my_package/Collision
```

which is correct. But when I try to run a python script that depends on this message like:

```
from my_package.msg import Collision
```

I get:

```
ImportError: No module named my_package.msg
```

Do you have any Ideas what I am doing wrong?

---

Some additional Info:

```
export | grep ROS
declare -x ROS
declare -x ROS_DISTRO="hydro"
declare -x ROS_ETC_DIR="/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros"
declare -x ROS_MASTER_URI="http://localhost:11311"
declare -x ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_ws/src:/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_mynavigationtest/src:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks"
declare -x ROS_ROOT="/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros"
declare -x ROS_TEST_RESULTS_DIR="/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_mynavigationtest/build/test_results"
```

and

```
echo $PYTHONPATH 
/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_mynavigationtest/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173703/importerror:-no-module-named-my_package.msg/) by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on ROS Answers with karma: 862 on 2014-06-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-06-16**:
For clarification: I have set the my_package as dependency in both CMakeLists.txt and package.xml of the package using the message.

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-06-24**:
Hi al-dev. I added the data. Do I have to add the oder path to the PYTHONPATH as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### I have a solution.

### The package with the message I used was in the folder `/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_ws/src` which was added to the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. But as I used it in another catkin workspace and it was **not** added to the PYTHONPATH as al-dev pointed out. This was because I edited the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH myself instead of calling `source devel/setup.bash`
but ->

The PYTHONPATH must include this subpath of a workspace `devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` if you want to use messages out of it.
*Thanks for your help!*

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-06-24**:
this is correct. but i can (again) due to my karma not mark it.

**Comment by [antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/23427/antonio/) on 2015-11-18**:
I am not sure I understand if you are suggesting a fix. Should one modify the PYTHONPATH variable to fix the problem? And if so, how should PYTHONPATH be modified?